# Error in first argument GIMP batch threshold in WSL

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gimp, script-fu

I am having trouble using the [GIMP batch commands in WSL](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

I have a file with several `.png` files and I am trying to apply threshold on all of them using the gimp batch, the documentation in gimp says how to run the commands, yet I get errors when I run a script almost copied from the documentation.

Here are some attempt-error pairs

```sh
gimp -i -b '(gimp-drawable-threshold "*.png" 6 0 0.5)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

```
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-drawable-threshold
```

Similar for

```sh
gimp -i -b '(gimp-threshold "*.png" 0 0.5)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

```
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-threshold
```

I couldn't find in the docs how arguments are numbered for ScriptFu in GIMP, so I first assumed that the 6 from the first attempt was wrong, but testing with gimp-threshold showed that it is alright.

Having realized that the `"*.png"` is likely wrong, I searched around and found people writing the filename argument with escapes (`\"`), but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please do explicitly mention the link from where you're copy-pasting the code you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you explore the Procedure Browser in GIMP (Help>>Procedure Browser)

But to give you the quick answer, gimp-threshold takes a drawable ID as the first parameter (which is a number) not a file name.

You would need to write a script that opens a file and then finds the ID of the layer that you want to operate on, and presumably then saves the file.

Comment: Oh, I understand my mistake now. I have been so blind.

Comment: @SaelbenNoa On the other hand you can do this kind of processing with ImageMagick, which is designed for batch usage.